# C# Display array of strings with diffrent console-colors, depending on odd/even string length in the array

Tags: c#

My program is compiling and is almost giving the correct output, but while checking if the string is even or odd. the console is freezing and gets stuck on the line that checks if the string is even or odd.

I don't know if this is a math problem or me not understanding how to use for loops/arrays with each other.

The exercise states the following:

> Create a string-array with 20 positions. Ask the user to enter several words, and store these words
> in the array. Stop reading words when the array is completely filled, or when the user enters an empty
> word (Length = 0). Finally, display all words in the same sequence as they were entered, use yellow
> for words with odd length, and use red for words with even length.

the expected output:

[image]

```
string[] word = new string[20]; // create array
int count = 0;

// fill array with words
for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
{
    Console.ResetColor();
    Console.Write("Enter a word: ");
    word[i] = Console.ReadLine();
    if (word[i].Length == 0) // if length of word[i] is equal to 0 then the loop stops
    {
        i = word.Length;
    }
}
// Display words in an array
for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
{
    if (word[i].Length % 2 == 0)// checks if string length in word[] array is even or odd
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red; // make console text Yellow for 'even' strings
    }
    else
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow; // Make console text Red for 'odd' strings.
    }
    Console.Write("{0}\n", word[count]); // display the words in the array.
    Console.ResetColor(); // Reset the text color
    count++;
}
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("End of program");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Why `Console.Write("{0}\n", word[count]);` instead of `Console.Write("{0}\n", word[i]);`?

Comment: You are resetting the color of the console way to many times. There is no need to reset it at all inside the first loop where you are filling up the array. And there is no need to call it inside the second loop at all. Reset it once that loop ends.

Comment: Also, the counter `count` should be incrementing inside the first loop, and your second loop should have the upper bound set to that value. Otherwise you will be looping null strings if the user hasn't filled up the array completely.

Comment: `Console.Write("{0}\n", word[count])` i used 'count' to let the program know what element in the array to display.

Comment: And last but not least, to exit a `loop` you use `break`; you don't set the value of the loop variable.

Comment: your comments for setting the console color don't match the colors you actually set

Comment: @Tommy in your implementation `count` and `i` have the same value. `count` is redundant in your code, read my comments on how you should use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's few things you could change :

```
            string[] word = new string[20]; // create array
            int count = 0;

            // fill array with words
            for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.Write("Enter a word: ");
                word[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                if (word[i].Length == 0) // if length of word[i] is equal to 0 then the loop stops
                {
                    break; // exit loop
                }
                count ++; // increase count by 1;
            }
            // Display words in an array
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                if (word[i].Length % 2 == 0)// checks if string length in word[] array is even or odd
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red; // make console text Yellow for 'even' strings
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow; // Make console text Red for 'odd' strings.
                }
                Console.Write("{0}\n", word[i]); // display the words in the array.
                Console.ResetColor(); // Reset the text color
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("End of program");
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: This works for me, now i understand what i did wrong. upvoted! 
The added comments helped me understand it.

Comment: @Tommy also keep in mind that after "break" in loop count will not be incremented.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you initialize your string array with 20. But when you input less then 20 words the ramaining strings are `null`. And `null % 2` doesn't work

You could check if string is `null`. Or a better way is to use List instead of Array.

```
List<string> words = new List<string>(20);
```

Then add your words with `words.Add(Console.ReadLine());` and loop the list with

```
foreach (string word in words) {...}
```

Comment: The exercise explicitly states that arrays should be used. The problem is that the OP is not using the variable `count` correctly to keep track of how many string are stored inside the array.

Comment: ok right. then at least the null value should be checked: `if(words[i]!= null)`

Comment: no need, you increment `count` in the first loop and you limit the second loop to that value. That would be the cleanest approach using fixed sized arrays.